# Model property is always null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For some reason the Owner property is always null, I'm not sure what could be causing this as the rest of the class properties are loading fine. The only difference here is that the properties type is not primitive.

**Model Code**

```
#region : Project :
[Table("Project")]
public class Project
{
    ...   
    public UserAccount Owner { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Line in the database**

```
ProjectID = 61
CreatedDate = 2013-05-26 17:04:07.480
ProjectName = 'test'
Owner_Username = 'someusername'
UserAccount_Username = 'someusername'
```

**Creation of the Context DbSet**

```
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

**Attempt to retrieve the owner**

```
Project _Project = _Db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);                
UserAccount _Owner = _Project.Owner; //<--- Null
```

### What could be preventing the owner object from being instantiated?

Comment: Where do you link the `Owner` property to the owner relation in the DB.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Owner is coming from a separate table, then the Entity Framework will not load it unless you indicate that you want it to be included in the query results.  Try this:

```
Project _Project = _Db.Projects.Include("Owner").FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);
```